# Export data from a Gridview to Excel and save it in a folder

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to export data from a Gridview to Excel and save that Excel file in a folder on the server. I have done the Excel generation part. But I am not able to save that in a folder.
Please find my code below.

**Code**

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "order.xls"));
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gridX.AllowPaging = false;
bindX();
gridX.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
for (int i = 0; i < gridX.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
{
   gridX.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#df5015");
}
gridX.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you. First fill the gridview control then use the RenderControl() method to render grid in excel to a specific path.

```
  public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
           server control at run time. */

    }

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\test.xls"))
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: the excel file is null

Comment: Now I am able to store it in a folder. But I need to prevent download. What to do?

Comment: Find it here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733336/prevent-download-when-exporting-gridview-to-excel

Comment: please check my edited answer. It will solve your null excel file problem.