# Prevent download when exporting Gridview to Excel

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to export data in a Gridview to Excel and store that file in a folder on server.
I have done this part. The only thing I want to do is,
I want to prevent downloading the Excel file.
Please find my code below.

```
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "order.xls"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gridX.AllowPaging = false;
    bindX();
    gridX.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    for (int i = 0; i < gridX.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        gridX.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#df5015");
    }
    gridX.RenderControl(htw);
    //Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    string renderedGridView = sw.ToString();
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Order/od/x");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "/order" + lblF.Text + ".xls", renderedGridView);
    sw.Close();
    htw.Close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means you only want to show this file as temp file ?

Comment: OR you can say that you want to show excel file in web page ?

Comment: I just want to save the file in a folder.

Comment: ok,It means you want to save file directly in a particular folder of user machine. But as per my knowledge you have to download file first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code by editing as per your need :

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadDataCompleted);

    client.DownloadDataAsync(e.Url);
}

void client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = textBox1.Text;
    File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, e.Result);
    MessageBox.Show("File downloaded");
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

### Code

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gridX.AllowPaging = false;
bindX();
gridX.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
for (int i = 0; i < gridX.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
{
   gridX.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#df5015");
}
gridX.RenderControl(htw);
//Response.Write(sw.ToString());
string renderedGridView = sw.ToString();
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Order/od/x");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "/order" + lblF.Text + ".xls", renderedGridView);
sw.Close();
htw.Close();
```